# Java - get the last element in a JsonObject

Tags: java, gson, element, json

I am using java to pull this Json object off the internet.

How would i get just the last element of the json object?

The key is a timecode but i was wondering if it is possible to skip using the JsonObject.get(TIMECODE);  method and just get the last element of the object?

This is the json object returned:

`{"daily":{"1437436800000":271,"1437523200000":271,"1437609600000":271,"1437696000000":271,"1437782400000":271,"1437868800000":271}}`

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee on the order of the properties in a JSON object. The last in textual sequence is not necessarily the last in time sequence.

Comment: @Henry hmm that's strange. Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

OK i have found a solution.

The .keys() method was not available to me when using the gson library. This method was available in the Maven Repository: org.json

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Object> getListFromJsonObject(JSONObject jObject) throws JSONException {
      List<Object> returnList = new ArrayList<Object>();
      Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();

      List<Long> keysList = new ArrayList<Long>();
      while (keys.hasNext()) {
        keysList.add(Long.parseLong(keys.next()));

      }
      Collections.sort(keysList); //sort the list

      for (Long key : keysList) {


        returnList.add(jObject.get(key.toString()));
      }

      return returnList;
    }
```